# Passing objects as parameters, no viable overloaded '='

Tags: c++, class, object

We are starting to cover objects and classes. I have three files: bigNumberTest.cpp, bigNumber.cpp, and bigNumber.h.

I'm having an error that say's "No viable overloaded '=' " in my main with:

```
bigNumberTest.cpp(provided by instructor)

int main(){
    //code
    sum = num1.addBig(num2);
    //code
}
```

I get a second error when I define the function in my bigNumber.cpp file with:

```
num[i] = num[i] + num2[i];
```

error here is: "Type 'bigNumber' does not provide a subscript operator."

```
bigNumber.cpp

void bigNumber::addBig(bigNumber num2){

    //sums the two arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_DIGITS; i++){
    num[i] = num[i] + num2[i];
    }
}
```

The overall code is not completely finished, but I would like to address these issues. I provided what I believed to be just the necessary code, but let me know if you need more info. I'm not fully understanding objects and classes just yet.

```
bigNumber.h file:

class bigNumber{

private:

    const int MAX_DIGITS = 100;
    int num[100];

public:

    void readBig();
    void addBig(bigNumber);
    void printBig();
};
```

Comment: Google "c++ operator overloading". Explaining the whole stuff of operator overloading might be too broad here.

Comment: If `addBig` has `void` return type, then `sum = num1.addBig(num2);` will not work (and makes no sense either), maybe think about what you are trying to do on that line

Comment: `num2[i]` should be `num2.num[i]`

Comment: Keep in mind your addition likely needs to handle carry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In main program, the operands are of type `bigNumber`. Compiler doesn't know how to perform an '=' operation on them. You'll have to write it yourself. Overload the '=' symbol that supports your datatype.

It should be something like this:

```
void bigNumber::operator=(bigNumber rhs)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<MAX_DIGITS ; i++)
    {
        this->num[i] = rhs.num[i];
    }
}
```

And for the second error, `num2` is just a variable. `num2` object has a variable `num` in it.

So, the actual code has to be:

```
bigNumber.cpp

void bigNumber::addBig(bigNumber num2){

    //sums the two arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_DIGITS; i++){
        this->num[i] = this->num[i] + num2.num[i];
    }
}
```

Try learning more about `this` operator.

Comment: Your answer is way off the real problem. See the comment by @M.M.

Comment: Usually "the compiler" provides `operator=` for user defined types. In this case, it would even do the right thing.